# Groupby using a sequence and computing sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, itertools-groupby

I've a dataframe like this,

```
  Name COST      Timestamp
0   c   8   2023-09-20 15:14:46
1   a   8   2023-09-20 15:14:48
2   c   9   2023-09-20 15:14:55
3   b   10  2023-09-20 15:15:00
4   c   4   2023-09-20 15:15:02
5   a   9   2023-09-20 15:15:04
6   b   3   2023-09-20 15:15:12
7   a   3   2023-09-20 15:15:17
8   c   6   2023-09-20 15:15:20
9   c   6   2023-09-20 15:15:29
```

What I want is to create a new dataframe. It will look for the sequence of a,b,c (order doesn't matter here) and sum_cost is sum of cost of a,b,c and it's time_stamp will be the last time_stamp of a,b,c whichever you get. Incase of multiple entries of a same name say like b,c,c,b,b,a then take the last c then then the last b and a.

*An detailed example*:

output should be from the given dataframe will be constructed like this, for first one it will take 'a' of index 1, 'c' of index 2 (as this came after 'c' of index 0) and 'b' of index 3, the sum_cost will be 27 for this group and timestamp will be 2023-09-20 00:14:26 which is of 'b' of index 3 as it came last for this group. And next group it will take 'c' of index 4, 'a' of index 5 and 'b' of index 6 and sum_cost will be 16 and timestamp will be 2023-09-20 00:06:51 which is of 'b' of index 6 as it came last of this sequence.

The output will look like this,

```
 sum_cost   Timestamp
0   27  2023-09-20 15:15:00
1   16  2023-09-20 15:15:12
```

Please help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: If order doesn't matter, why don't you take c/a/b as indices 0/1/3?

Comment: It's a synthetic example I created, consider this case: once c/a/b come maybe next the order is like b, b, c, c, a. In this case what will be the group is b/c/a. Am I clear or need more example?

Comment: OK, but is the provided output correct given your synthetic example? Or should it group together indices 0,1,3? Should the values be consecutive or not? Should the dataset be first sorted by timestamp? Can you skip values? Please clarify

Comment: Should it select the last a/b/c regardless of the alphabetical order? Or the last a/b/c in order? For example, in the array `[a,c,b,a,c]`, would it use the items at indexes `[0, 2, 4]`, or `[2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: And in `[c1,a2,c3,b4,c5,c6,a7,b8,a9]` should is group a2/c3/b4 and c6/a7/b8 because they are contiguous, or could you group c1/a2/b4, c3/a7/b8?

Comment: All those logics are possible but the code will be very different, that's why you **must** clarify the logic.

Comment: The output of the synthetic example is correct please follow the example how I constructed it. I basically want to group together a/b/c, again order doesn't matter it can come like a,c,c,c,b (it's basically a/c/b here) or it can come like b,b,b,a,c (here it's b/a/c). You can't skip values.

If this help you can use timestamp also, the timestamp from top to bottom is in a increasing order. I'll edit the timestamp once as currently it's random.

Comment: @RufusBarnes it will select the 2nd one [2, 3, 4]

Comment: @mozway [c1,a2,c3,b4,c5,c6,a7,b8,a9] in this example it will be first sample a2/c3/b4 sum_cost of these three and timstamp of b4 and then it will group c6/a7/b8 and sum_cost of these three and timstamp of b8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a custom grouper, for that a loop is required, here using a custom function:

```
def group_consecutive(s, target):
    out = []
    i = 0

    g = 1
    while i < len(s)-len(target)+1:
        if target == set(s.iloc[i:i+len(target)]):
            out.extend([g]*len(target))
            g += 1
            i += len(target)
        else:
            out.append(0)
            i += 1
    out.extend([0]*(len(target)-1))

    return pd.Series(out, index=s.index)

group = group_consecutive(df['Name'], {'a', 'b', 'c'})

out = df[group>0].groupby(group).agg({'COST': 'sum', 'Timestamp': 'last'})
```

Output:

```
   COST            Timestamp
1    27  2023-09-20 15:15:00
2    16  2023-09-20 15:15:12
```

Intermediate with group:

```
  Name  COST            Timestamp  group
0    c     8  2023-09-20 15:14:46      0
1    a     8  2023-09-20 15:14:48      1
2    c     9  2023-09-20 15:14:55      1
3    b    10  2023-09-20 15:15:00      1
4    c     4  2023-09-20 15:15:02      2
5    a     9  2023-09-20 15:15:04      2
6    b     3  2023-09-20 15:15:12      2
7    a     3  2023-09-20 15:15:17      0
8    c     6  2023-09-20 15:15:20      0
9    c     6  2023-09-20 15:15:29      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code
You need to change the path to your dataframe

```
from datetime import datetime 
import pandas as pd

df =pd.read_csv("df.csv")
a_tmp= b_tmp= c_tmp= max_tmp = datetime(1998, 5, 3)
a_value= b_value= c_value = None
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sum_cost','timestamp'])

for row in range(len(df)):
    if df['Name'][row] == 'a' and datetime.strptime(df['Timestamp'][row],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")> a_tmp:
        a_value = df['COST'][row]
        a_tmp = datetime.strptime(df['Timestamp'][row],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        if a_tmp > max_tmp:
            max_tmp = a_tmp
    elif  df['Name'][row] == 'b' and datetime.strptime(df['Timestamp'][row],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")> b_tmp:
        b_value = df['COST'][row]
        b_tmp = datetime.strptime(df['Timestamp'][row],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        if b_tmp > max_tmp:
            max_tmp = b_tmp
    elif df['Name'][row] == 'c' and datetime.strptime(df['Timestamp'][row],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")> c_tmp:
        c_value = df['COST'][row]
        c_tmp = datetime.strptime(df['Timestamp'][row],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        if c_tmp > max_tmp:
            max_tmp = c_tmp
    if a_value is not None and b_value is not None and c_value is not None:
        sum_of_value =  a_value+ b_value + c_value
        df2.loc[len(df2.index)] =[sum_of_value,max_tmp]
        a_tmp= b_tmp= c_tmp= max_tmp = datetime(1998, 5, 3)
        a_value =  b_value =  c_value = None
        
df2
```

Comment: I'm getting back a empty dataframe df2
. Can you please check once?

Comment: Do you have any errors ?

Comment: No I didn't get any errors. I created a dataframe df with the data I provided in the question. And then ran your code, and got a empty output df2.

Comment: I edited the code try again, it works for me with the sample of your dataframe

Comment: Okay sorry, I missed that you edited the code, I will try again. Thanks a lot for taking time and helping me out!

Comment: Thanks a lot it was little hard coded but serves the purpose.